# signalR with jquery mobile causing lot of problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, signalr

I am new to jquery mobile and signalR, and I am trying to add calling feature to my mobile app( built using jq mobile and js mainly), and I am getting this error

```
http://localhost:2286/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22callhub%22%7D%5D&_=1445088108694"
```

here is the layout of my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       // app.MapSignalR<EchoConnection>("/echo");
        //app.MapSignalR();
        app.MapSignalR("/Chat", new HubConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Sometimes I am also getting this error:

```
GET http://localhost:2286/6836b6171ec44d63b5d7a9aa110a5fa1/arterySignalR/ping?r…%2FApp%2Findex.html%23p-choices&browserName=Chrome+(Linux)&_=1445089928688 404 (Not Found)
```

also click event is not working inside my hub.
I am stuck between this signalR and click-ability problem from last four days.
for clicking I used onclick= "somefunction()" but that started to give me another error saying hub.start().done should be called before sent. I tried to change my hub Url too but that didn't helped,
if any of you have some idea then please come forward to help me.

```
<script src="Js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Js/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Chat/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:2***7/signalr";
callHub = $.connection.callHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {               
                $(document).on('click', '#btnCallUserAudio', function () {

                            // do something.....
                        });
                  });

</script>
<body>
   <div data-role="page" id="p-page1">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content ui-body-cf ui-responsive">
             <button id="btnCallUserAudio" type="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline wd90 callingBtns" style="" ></button>
          </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="ce">

    </div>
      <div data-role="page" id="p-page2">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content ui-body-cf ui-responsive">

          </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="ce">

    </div>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        many more pages


  </body>
```

Edit : - I searched about my issues on google, and tried things as mentioned in this link - 
 "[SignalR not always ready after start().done()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279550/signalr-not-always-ready-after-start-done)"
I added the setTimeOut() and " $.connection.hub.logging = true;" but it still not working, in console it is showing below mentioned things in blue color -
"
[12:16:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'callhub'.
[12:16:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/Chat/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22callhub%22%7D%5D'.
"

it is showing same things on the website part too but there it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

after lot of searching on google I didn't find anything useful,but by using "$.connection.hub.logging = true;" in both of my project(i.e. jq mobile and website) I get to know which versions of signalR javascript file I am using in my mobile and website part, and there I see that I am using older version of signalR on website part, after replacing signalR from my mobile part with signalR from website...it is started working nicely.
Now my project is working fine but I don't have an idea why it was not working with the latest version, so any help regarding this will be appreciated.