# 'Signal R' client side .js not receiving any response from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, signalr

I wrote a script which is working as expected.But sometimes it doesn't get any response from server side which is very confusing ,because I've debugged the application several times but no exceptions and errors occurred while the connection id remain constraint.Can anyone please help me out what is actually happening?

```
$(function() { 
    $.connection.hub.url = '@Url.Content("~/signalr")'; 
    var Hub = $.connection.chatHub; 
    $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ["webSockets", "longPolling", "serverSentEvents","foreverFrame"] })
                    .done( function() { Hub.server.register(); })
                    .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); }); 
    $.connection.hub.logging = true; 
    $.connection.hub.error(function (err) { console.log("Error Signal R:" +  JSON.stringify(err)); });
    Hub.client.onBrodcast = function (id, msg) { $('body #chat_show_').prepend($.trim(msg)); }; 
});
```

Comment: You need to explain further. Please share your script if possible.

Comment: $(function(){
$.connection.hub.url = '@Url.Content("~/signalr")';
var Hub = $.connection.chatHub;
$.connection.hub.start({
transport: ["webSockets", "longPolling", "serverSentEvents","foreverFrame"]
}).done(function(){
 Hub.server.register();
}).fail(function(){

console.log('Could not connect');
});
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
console.log("Error Signal R:" + JSON.stringify(err));
});Hub.client.onBrodcast = function (id, msg) {
$('body #chat_show_').prepend($.trim(msg));
};
});

Comment: sometimes it does not work as expected.can you please help me?

Comment: By default, the hub location is the current server; if you are connecting to a different server, specify the URL before calling the start method, as shown in the following example:

    `$.connection.hub.url = '<your-backend-url>';` Would you please set the URL specifically, rather than Url.Content?

Comment: It is working as expected but sometimes it is not working, if I clean the browser cache it is working again.It confuses me a lot, even no error traces.

Comment: Do you agree with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279550/signalr-not-always-ready-after-start-done/16973824#16973824

Comment: Can you remove `foreverFrame` and change the start method to : `strat()` or `start(({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] }))`, since it may timeout during connect, and see if the issue exists?