# $.connection.myHub.server.announce on clients view not worked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using SignalR package on my ASP.NET MVC project. I want to show alert message on clients view but it never showed up.

This is my `MyHub.cs` file, containing methods for clients

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Klien //my namespace
{
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Announce(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.Announce(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my code on `SignalR.js` file

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.log("It Worked!");
        $.connection.myHub.server.announce("Connected!");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("Error!");
    });
    $.connection.myHub.client.announce = function (message) {
        alert(message);
    };
        
}, 5000);
```

The `$.connection.hub` is successfully worked by showing the "It Worked!" message on the console. When I try to check this on console `console.log($.connection.myHub)` it says that have connected with /signalr but actually **I want to announce the alert message "Connected!" on the client view**. I'm using setTimeout because the code `$.connection.hub.start().done` never run if I not mention it ([SignalR not always ready after start().done()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279550/signalr-not-always-ready-after-start-done)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one method defined before the start per the documentation.

I would remove that timeout because you are essentially creating a new connection every 5 seconds which is not needed. You can see below how I attempt a reconnect if the user gets disconnected.

```
//your method here
$.connection.myHub.client.announce = function (message) {
    alert(message);
};

//Start the connection only after at least one method has been declared.
$.connection.hub
    .start()
    .done(function () { 
       //your server call here
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log("An error occurred connecting to the server.");
    });
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```